# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault for PyQt ui

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I find a segmentation fault on machine 1 with centOS 6.6 when I run the following:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
>>> QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#7F462C"),2,QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
```

but it works fine on machine 2 with centOS 6.5 with same version of python3 pyqt4(4.9.6) and qt(4.7.1)

gdb gives me the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000b400000229 in ?? ()
```

Although there is no segmentation fault when I change the line to this:

```
>>> QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(127,70,44),2,QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
```

Comment: I suspected either a corrupt installation of python or hardware errors.

Comment: Although very unlikely, but it might be so. Can you tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: If it's hardware, likely suspects are RAM.  Check system logs and dmesg for confirmation. If you see other processes crashing, that could be your confirmation. Try memtest86 to confirm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86