# PyQt Segmentation fault in addItems for a combox

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

When I run the following code it generates a segmentation fault:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
methodNameComboBox=QtGui.QComboBox()
methodNameComboBox.addItems(['a','b'])
methodNameComboBox.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but changing it to this works just fine

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
methodNameComboBox=QtGui.QComboBox()
methodNameComboBox.addItem('a' )
methodNameComboBox.addItem('b' )
methodNameComboBox.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

so the fault is generated by the method **addItems** .

gdb gives me the following result:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000b400000229 in ?? ()
```

using python 3.3.0 qt 4.7.1 and pyqt 4.9.6 is there something wrong with any of the installations?

## EDIT:

this is the same as another statement I was trying to use.
See: [Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault for PyQt ui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27753568/2436483)

Comment: Since you are using such old versions of qt and pyqt, it is overwhelmingly likely that these issues are caused by bugs in those libraries. Unless you can upgrade to much more recent versions of qt and pyqt, there's not much point in posting questions like this on SO. You should probably ask on the CentOS forums whether other users with similar setups can reproduce the problems.

Comment: @ekhumoro I understand that. But, this problem comes in centOS 6.6 (final) release while works fine in centOS 6.5 (final)

Comment: That seems to suggest even more strongly that the problem may be specific to centOS. What are the exact version differences between them with regard to python, qt and pyqt? Do you get the same problems when using `QString/QStringList` in your examples? To test this, either use python2, or for python3, put `import sip; sip.setapi("QString", 1)` before the pyqt imports.

Comment: python3, pyqt and qt are all exactly the same.
I tried to put the line before my QtGui import. But still, I'm stuck with the same segmentation fault.

Comment: But did you try using `QString/QStringList`? Do something like `s = QtCore.QStringList() << 'a' << 'b'; methodNameComboBox.addItems(s)`. Or in your other example, try `QtGui.QColor(QtCore.QString("#7F462C"))`.